# com.google.api.services.drive.model.File size of id

Tags: sql, file, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using google api to upload and download files to google drive.
I need to save the id of the file in a relational database.
Should I use a type TEXT or can I fix the maximal size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the length isn't specified, you can make no reliable assumptions about length.

However, in practice, there are some lengths that are reasonable to consider safe. For the Drive ID, I would personally use `varchar(1000)`. Certainly no need to use Text.